# Apache proxyPass with x-forwarded-for not working

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, x-forwarded-for

I have an issue with Apache X-Forwarded-For.

Here is the scenario  
I have a server which will forward the request to an Apache Server. And the Apache server has multiple Proxy forwards.  
What the issue i am facing now is even though I am able to print the client IP address in apache logs using X-Forwarded-For header it some how couldn't forward the same X-Forwarded-For header to Proxypass requests.  
I have already included below line in httpd.conf file.
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

However, the application where request is forwarded to using proxypass always reads remote ip address as
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 and X-FORWARDED-HEADER is empty.

What am I doing wrong and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you enable mod_remoteip?